# How to evaluate $\int _0^1{(x^x)}^{{(x^x)}^{.^{.^.}}}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I found this integral [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3602796/does-my-proof-show-that-int-01-fracdxx-converges/3602810#3602810)

And the person says this equals $ \frac{\pi ^2}{12}$

But I tried to solve this and could not do it and I was unable to find any thing online.

I tried many ways but could not even go through variable transformation by assuming ${(x^x)}^{{(x^x)}^{.^{.^.}}} = t$

How should I proceed?

Comment: Note that the integrand is more simply written as $$\exp{\left(-W{\left(-\ln{\left(x^x\right)}\right)}\right)}$$where $W(z)$ denotes the principal branch of the Lambert-W function. Numerically your statement appears to be true.

Comment: I'm sorry but I guess the answer is `1`. It is easy to proof with graph

Comment: @EgorRandomize: I'm sorry but what's really "easy" is to make mistakes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using @Peter Foreman(s comment, we need to compute
$$I=\int_0^1 \exp\big[-W{\left(-x\ln{\left(x\right)}\right)}\big]\,dx$$

Considering the infinite series
$$\exp\big[-W{\left(-x\ln{\left(x\right)}\right)}\big]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{n-1} }{n!}\left(x \log (x)\right)^{n-1}$$
$$\int_0^1 \left(x \log (x)\right)^{n-1}\,dx=-e^{i n\pi  }\, n^{-n}\, \Gamma (n)$$ this makes
$$I=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{i n \pi }\, \Gamma (n)}{n\, n!}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{i \pi  n}}{n^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{12}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I guess the answer is `1`. It is easy to proof with graph.